# .Net Core, LightInject: How to set up DI via properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, light-inject

Can't set up dependency injection via properties in a class...

I googled everything and looked through all the documentation, so I couldn't find anything how to configure on .net core mvc... Help me please

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    protected IUserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

    public HomeController()
    { }
}
```

DI

```
public class CompositionRoot : ICompositionRoot
{
   public void Compose(IServiceRegistry services)
   {
       services.RegisterScoped<IUserRepository>, UserRepository>();
   }
}
```

Constructor injection works well, but property injection fails.

*Most likely you need to add some additional package and additional settings, but I do not know what*

I use:

- ASP.NET CORE MVC 3.1
- LightInject 6.3.4 (latest version)

Comment: Try to set property with local variable as: private IUserRepository userRepository; public IUserRepository objUserRepository{ set { this.userRepository = value; } get { return userRepository; } }

Comment: It didn't help, it doesn't depend on it. @imran

Comment: If ctor injection is working, what you can do is just set your property instead of the setting a private field.

`public HomeController(IUserRepository  userRepository) { UserRepository  = userRepository }`

Comment: @BonMacalindong but I need to inject the dependency through a property, not a constructor